# What happens if I install github branch package and R CRAN package with same name?

Tags: r, github

Suppose I did

> install.packages("Geo")

then I did

> devtools::install_github("Geo@ronaldo")

What happens? Are they stored in different locations? If so how do I import either one using library? If not, do they overwrite? Where can I find info about what happens?

Comment: They overwrite (assuming you didn't change `.libPaths()` in the meantime).  Installations do _not_ carry a version marker and simply occupy a directory with the package name.  So no way to disambiguate.  It is really just your write order: whichever of the two you installed last is the one present.

Comment: Also side question, I can do 
library("Geo")
but when I do
packageVersion("Geo") 
it says it cannot find package. What's going on?

Comment: That is odd.  Maybe double-check on the filesystem that it is where you think it should be.  (You can ask R too:  `IP <- installed.packages()` lists them.)